# Backbone Modals - proper approach

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I working with my model and modal which is common for all models, I wonder what is the proper approach in handling the id of deleting model, my idea was:

on delete link trigger the function in model:

```
modal : function(e) {
    var edu_id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id'),
        confirm = $(e.currentTarget).data('confirm');
        newModal = new Modal({ model: new Backbone.Model({header:"Potwierdź", content: confirm}) });

    // we are waiting for OK button in modal, when event occured FIRE!
    newModal.on('fire',this.fire,this);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I'm listening for the event 'fire' which i triggering when user clicked on OK button, the main issue is how could I pass the edu_id for deleting element? Is that generally good approach or I should make it in different way.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to myself ;), how I did it is just trigger event in child event with additional param:

```
this.trigger('fire',model_id);
```

and it works fine.